# Redirecting to a mobile sub-domain using 51degrees

Tags: c#, mobile, 51degrees

I'm using the 51degrees API for mobile redirection: http://51degrees.codeplex.com/

- The desktop site is located at http://www.mydomain.com.
- The mobile site is located at http://m.mydomain.com.

When a mobile device is detected, using 51degrees, I am able to redirect from from any desktop page to the mobile *homepage* using the 51degrees configuration only. I.e. http://www.mydomain.com/somepage to  http://m.somepage.com/default.

What I am unable to do is redirect to the same page, i.e. from http://www.mydomain.com/somepage to  http://m.somepage.com/somepaage.

Is it possible to redirect to the same page?

Comment: Can you share your 51Degrees regex/code for doing the domain redirect please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**: Use 51degrees for the mobile detection part only and wire up the redirect yourself.  Remove the `<redirect>` element from your web.config and try something like this in your Global.asax file:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://m.mydomain.com" + Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

**Option 2**:  In the `<redirect>` element in the web.config file, add the property `originalUrlAsQueryString=true`.  This will send a query string called **origUrl** to the mobile homepage giving you the option to redirect to the mobile version of the requested page.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about how to configure it to redirect to mobile versions of a page in section 2.1.2 in 51Degrees.mobi [User Guide](http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/Foundation/UserGuide.aspx).

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of that section in your answer, which should be readable standing alone. Right now, you're just telling him someone else has his answer (not to mention link rot).